# Generate data set using unknown distribution

Tags: algorithm-analysis, np-complete, np-hard

For my research work, I need to generate dataset by using some standard statistical distribution. I have seen Unknown distribution for dataset generation. I do not have any idea about unknown distribution and how to generate data using this distribution. Could you please clarify what is unknown distribution? My problem belongs to NP class, to test my algorithm, I need to generate dataset using different statistical distribution.

Comment: A distribution is *unknown* if it is not known. The word here is used in a non-technical sense.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus How one would  experiment his algorithm on unknown distribution. I mean if distribution is unknown then how one could generate it. Please reply.

Comment: You cannot generate a distribution if it's unknown. It's like factoring a number without knowing it. How would you do that? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you. I was also thinking about it.